# Relative path to absolute path in C#?

Tags: c#, relative-path, absolute-path

I have xml files that contain href file paths to images (e.g. "....\images\image.jpg"). The hrefs contain relative paths. Now, I need to extract the hrefs to the images and turn them into absolute paths in the file system.

I know about the GetFullPath method, but I tried it and it only seems to work from the CurrentDirectory set, which appears to be C: so I don't see how I could use that. And still, I have the absolute path of the file containing the hrefs, and the href relative paths, so since it is a simple task for me to count back the number of "....\" parts based on the absolute path of the containing file, it seems there must be a way to do this programmatically as well.

I'm hoping there's some simple method I just don't know about! Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a desktop or web applicaiton?

Comment: Possible Duplicate [how to convert relative path to absolute path in windows application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1399008/299327).

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Assuming you know the real directory the XML file lives in use Path.Combine, e.g.

```
var absolute_path = Path.Combine(directoryXmlLivesIn, "..\images\image.jpg");
```

If you want to get back the full path with any ..'s collapsed then you can use:

```
Path.GetFullPath((new Uri(absolute_path)).LocalPath);
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem was apparently that I had forgotten to get the directory of the xml file first, I had tried Combine, but with the absolute path of the file, which didn't work. I don't know which of all these answers was first, the time shows the same, but you pointed out to get the directory, so I chose your answer. Thanks to all though!

Comment: With a little bit of experimentation it appears that `(new Uri(absolute_path)).LocalPath` does the same thing as `Path.GetFullPath(absolute_path)` so one or the other should suffice.

Comment: Note that Uri has special handling of "#" or "&" which you don't want when handling paths and filenames!

Comment: @MatsW: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.localpath states `Gets a local operating-system representation of a file name.` so in this case, no special handling is to be expected.

Answer (score 178):

```
string exactPath = Path.GetFullPath(yourRelativePath);
```

works

Comment: this the right answer to the question 'how do you convert a relative path to an absolute path?' the OP just wanted to know the answer to 'how do you stick to bits of paths together?'

Comment: At first I thought this didn't work, but it does. If you feed your relative path of C:\test\A\..\B\test.txt   The output will be C:\test\B\test.txt

Answer (score 36):

This worked.

```
var s = Path.Combine(@"C:\some\location", @"..\other\file.txt");
s = Path.GetFullPath(s);
```

Answer (score 15):

It's the best way to convert the `Relative` path to the `Absolute` one!

```
string absolutePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(relativePath);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use Path.Combine with the "base" path, then GetFullPath on the results.

```
string absPathContainingHrefs = GetAbsolutePath(); // Get the "base" path
string fullPath = Path.Combine(absPathContainingHrefs, @"..\..\images\image.jpg");
fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(fullPath);  // Will turn the above into a proper abs path
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried [`Server.MapPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx) method. Here is an example

```
string relative_path = "/Content/img/Upload/Reports/59/44A0446_59-1.jpg";
string absolute_path = Server.MapPath(relative_path);
//will be c:\users\.....\Content\img\Upload\Reports\59\44A0446_59-1.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
//used in an ASP.NET MVC app
private const string BatchFilePath = "/MyBatchFileDirectory/Mybatchfiles.bat"; 
var batchFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(BatchFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `Path.Combine`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx