# Setting a root path to use relative paths from

Tags: c#, uri, relative-path

Is there a way to set a 'root' or a base path to then use relative paths from in C#?

So for example, say I had the path:

```
C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Document.txt
```

Could I then use this path, instead of the programs assembly, to be the base path. So this would then allow me to use something like:

```
..\..\Pictures\Photo.png
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796254/relative-path-to-absolute-path-in-c?rq=1

Comment: Yes this worked thank you!

Answer (score 0):

why not do:

```
string RootPath = string.empty

#if DEBUG
    RootPath = "C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Document.txt"
#else
    RootPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass)).Location;
#endif

var newPath = Path.Combine(RootPath, "..\..\Pictures\Photo.png");
```

Comment: Where I believe this would work, it's not quite in the context of what I need. However I found the top answer here to work for me. This questions is really a duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796254/relative-path-to-absolute-path-in-c?rq=1