# C# Visual Studio 2015 load xml inside solution

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I have a XML file in my solution `Xml/file.xml`

I wrote:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(@"Xml\file.xml");
```

My `file.xml` properties are:

```
Build Action = Content
Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always
```

In debug mode it works, but when I pubblish the solution, it searches the file in:

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Xml\file.xml
```

What is the solution?

Thanks

Comment: You can [determine the actual path (depending on what app type this is)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path)

Comment: When you publish, you are changing your exe's location. Your root directory also changes to this new location. Move your file to the path its looking for or set an [absolute path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796254/relative-path-to-absolute-path-in-c) for the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file size isn't huge, I would personally usually do something like this as an **embedded resource** so that the XML is included inside your compiled code, and you don't need to load an external file ....

Set the properties:

```
Build Action = EmbeddedResource
```

and then use code something like this:

```
// adapt as needed
string yourResourceName = "YourAssembly.Xml.File.Xml";

// load the embedded resource
Stream resourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(yourResourceName);

// if resource is found
if (resourceStream != null) {
    tXElement root = XElement.Load(resourceStream);
    // do whatever you want to do ....
}
```