# Absolute Path from Relative Path with a different current folder

Tags: c#, .net, path

I need to get an absolute path from a relative path, but using a folder other than where the assembly is executing from to resolve `"."` and `".."`. `Path.GetFullPath` does not provide such an overload.

For example, say I have the following path:

`..\MyOtherFolder\foo.bar`

And the folder the assembly is executing from is:

`c:\users\me\desktop\source\myproj\bin\debug\`

but it could, in practice, be located anywhere.

I want to specify the "current" folder as `c:\test` so the `".."` resolves to `"c:\"`.

Does anyone know if this is built into the .NET framework anywhere? If not, I plan on making a Utility method, but I thought I'd check first (especially since there's no static extension methods...).

EDIT:

`Path.Combine` will not work. All this method essentially does is concatenate the two strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate [how to convert relative path to absolute path in windows application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1399008/299327).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're currently in `c:\test` and you want to get `c:\MyOtherFolder\foo.bar` without knowing that you're in `c:\test` you want to do;

```
 Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"..\MyOtherFolder"; //navigation accepts relative path
 string fullPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); // returns full path
```

After that you may want to set the current directory back to your previous location.

Comment: Although changing the current directory is not really ideal (in a Utility method it is non-obvious that its not thread-safe), this works for my current purposes.

Comment: This hurts me physically... :(

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried

```
Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(@"C:\test", @"..\MyOtherFolder\foo.bar"))
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

```
public string FullPathRelativeTo(string root, string partialPath)
{
    string oldRoot = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    try {
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(root);
        return Path.GetFullPath(partialPath);
    }
    finally {
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(oldRoot);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
new DirectoryInfo( @"..\MyOtherFolder\foo.bar" ).FullName
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [Path.Combine(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) method, it has to help you to achieve what you want..

Comment: I get the impression the OP is assuming he doesn't know that he's in `c:\tests`, he could be anywhere, and wants to get a full path given a relative path so `Path.Combine` will not work.