# ASP,NET MVC change a virtual path to a physical path when uploading a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, server.mappath

I need to save the files somewhere else because the server that this application is getting full

How would I change the virtual path to a physical path?

This is my original controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(FormularioDoUploadViewModel formularioDoUploadViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                List<DetalhesDoArquivoViewModel> detalhesDosArquivos = new List<DetalhesDoArquivoViewModel>();

                for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
                {
                    var file = Request.Files[i];

                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        DetalhesDoArquivoViewModel detalhesDoArquivo = new DetalhesDoArquivoViewModel()
                        {
                            FileName = fileName,
                            Extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName)
                        };

                        detalhesDosArquivos.Add(detalhesDoArquivo);
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/Upload/"), detalhesDoArquivo.Id + detalhesDoArquivo.Extension);
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                    }

                }

                formularioDoUploadViewModel.DetalhesDoArquivo = detalhesDosArquivos;

                _uploadServices.AdicionarArquivo(formularioDoUploadViewModel);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(formularioDoUploadViewModel);
        }
```

and I want to insert this path into the variable path:

```
 var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"C:\Users\bwm6\Desktop\uploads"), detalhesDoArquivo.Id + detalhesDoArquivo.Extension);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the relative path with your absolute path. Be sure your permissions are in order to write to the directory. You will can use `System.IO.File` to access the systems files.  This link my help you understand how to do so: [How to convert a relative path to an absolute path in a Windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399008/how-to-convert-a-relative-path-to-an-absolute-path-in-a-windows-application)