# Find absolute path in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the full path to a file.
I have the "end" of the path like:

```
\some_folder\myTextFile.txt
```

and the "beginning" like:

```
c:\Users\me\...
```

how do I find the absolute path to the textfile?

Comment: `System.IO.Path.Combine`

Comment: [How to convert a relative path to an absolute path in a Windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1399008/995714): [`Path.GetFullPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.IO
(...)
string relativePath = "\some_folder\myTextFile.txt";
string absolutePath = Path.GetFullPath(relativePath);
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

```
 string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
foreach(string a in fileEntries)
{

    if(a.Contains("\some_folder\myTextFile.tx"))
   {
         return a
   }
  else
  {
     continue;
  }

}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.